# How do I call specific interfaces that are implemented by some objects in a List? Java

Tags: java, list, generics, interface, instanceof

Lets say I have a basic animal class

```
abstract class Animal {
// basic animal code
}
```

and now I have 2 different animals...

```
public class Dog extends Animal{
// dog code
}
```

and

```
public class Bird extends Animal implements Flyable{

    // bird code
    @Override
    public void fly() {
        System.out.println("flap flap");
    }

}
```

Flyable is a simple interface that holds a single method:

```
public void fly();
```

if i have a list of animals and i want to loop through it, telling the birds to fly but leaving the dogs alone, how might I achieve this this?

```
public class Test {

    public static List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        animals.add(new Bird("flop"));
        animals.add(new Dog("plop"));

        for(Fly f : animals) { // exception here because of mismatch of types
            f.flap();
        }

    }

}
```

The only option I have found so far is using instanceof to determine whether a class implements the Flyable interface, but a quick google search suggests this is bad for business.
Sources such as:
https://www.quora.com/Is-using-instanceof-in-Java-consider-bad-practice-Any-alternative-to-using-this-keyword
dismiss the use of instanceof as bad design.

I feel like there is an intuitive way of doing this that I have seen before, but cannot find a good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Flyable is a simple interface that holds a single method:
>
> ```
> public void fly();
> ```

I suppose that was a typo, since the method you call is named `flap` and not `fly`.

You can solve the issue by using the `instanceof` keyword to check if a class `is-a` superclass.

```
for(Animal animal : animals) { // loop through all animals
    if(animal instanceof Flyable) { // if that animal IS-A Flyable (so it can fly)
        ((Flyable) animal).flap(); // cast to Flyable and let it fly!
    }
}
```

---

> The only option I have found so far is using instanceof to determine whether a class implements the Flyable interface, but a quick google search suggests this is bad for business

It's not bad at all in my opinion. And it's the only way to accomplish your task.

Comment: any way to avoid `instanceof` ? The OP says "*The only option I have found so far is using instanceof to determine whether a class implements the Flyable interface, but a quick google search suggests this is bad for business*"

Comment: @ChandlerBing Don't think so. If you want to call a specific method, you need to check if the type allows you to do it, then cast.

Comment: It was a typo, just fixed it. I have always avoided instanceof because every time i look online, everyone says it's "bad" practise. But if this is the best way, then i will grudgingly do it,

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Is-using-instanceof-in-Java-consider-bad-practice-Any-alternative-to-using-this-keyword

Comment: @John The point is correct. However, in this scenario I think it's perfectly fine to use `instanceof`. even if `Bird` is an `Animal`, it has some specific behaviour: it can fly. So it's perfectly fine to use `instanceof` to call that method. If you want to avoid it, maybe you can create a general `move` method inside the `Animal` class, which can be called on all `Animal`s. Then, inside `Bird,move` you can make it flap instead of just moving. But a bird can also just move without flying, so I don't think that would solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

When you implement the `Flyable` interface that contains a `fly()` method declaration in the `Animal` class, you simply define that each and every subclass of animal has a flying ability.

In my opinion, using `instanceof` is a bad practice due to the fact that it makes the code pretty confusing: In one hand Dog has a fly() implementation (it indirectly implements the Flyable interface via Animal class), and on the other hand, you don't invoke it when you call fly() on the interface instance.

You have at least 2 ways to prevent `Dog` from having a flying ability, these are my two favorites:

1. You can create 2 classes, `FlyingAnimal` and `NonFlyingAnimal` which both extend the `Animal` class while the `FlyingAnimal` class implements the Flyable interface and the `NonFlyingAnimal` doesn't.
   The Bird will extend the `FlyingAnimal` class while the Dog will extend the `NonFlyingAnimal` class.
   In this way, you can create a `FlyingAnimal` list, iterate it, and invoke the `fly()` method on each and every one of its flying members (the dog isn't one of them).
2. Use the Strategy Design pattern:

```
public interface Flyable {
    String fly();
}

class ItFlys implements Flyable {
    public String fly() {
        return "I can fly";
    }
}

class CantFly implements Flyable {
    public String fly() {
        return "I can't fly";
    }
}

public class Animal {

    private String name;
    private double height;
    private int weight;
    private String favFood;
    private double speed;
    private String sound;

    public Flyable flyingType;

    public String tryToFly() {
        return flyingType.fly();
    }

    public void setFlyingAbility(Flyable newFlyType) {
        flyingType = newFlyType;
    }
}

public class Bird extends Animal{
    public Bird() {
        super();
        flyingType = new ItFlys();
    }   
}

public class Dog extends Animal{
    public Dog() {
        super();
        flyingType = new CantFly();
    }   
}
```

In this way, you set a flying type to each and every subclass of `Animal`.
When you invoke the `fly()` method on a `Dog` class, you will get a "non-flying animal" behavior.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to organize your objects such that you don't have to inspect each one in order to determine what to do with it.  For example, you might maintain a `Kingdom` class with various collections of `Animal`, including a `Flyable` collection.  Iterating over the Flyable collection wouldn't require testing whether each instance was Flyable.  If you have other classes that operate on only Flyable objects, they, too, would not have to test each member, leading to cleaner code with less work.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of possibilites you can use:

1. Put `fly()` in the base class as an abstract method. Make `Dog`'s implementation throw a `CannotFlyException`, or otherwise implement some "non-flying" behavior. Then iterate over your `List<Animal>` using

   ```
   try {
       animal.fly();
   catch (CannotFlyException() cfe) {
       System.out.println("grounded!");
   }
   ```
2. Give your Animal() class an abstract method that lists supported operations, then test every member to see if it implements the fly() method:

   ```
   public abstract class Animal {
       private Set<String> behaviors;

       public Animal() {
           behaviors = new HashSet<String>();
       }

       public Set<String> getBehaviors() {
           return behaviors;
       }
   }

   public class Dog extends Animal {
       public Dog() {
           super();
           behaviors.add("fetch");
       }

       public String fetch(String fetched) {
           return "Dog fetched " + fetched;
       }     
   }

   public class Bird extends Animal implements Flyable {
       public Dog() {
           super();
           behaviors.add("fly");
       }

       @Override
       public String fly() {
           return "flap flap";
       }     
   }

   ....

   List<Animal> animals = MagicalAnimalListCreator.MakeAnimalList();
   for (Animal animal : animals) {
       if (animal.getBehaviors().contains("fly")) {
           animal.fly();
       }
   }
   ```
3. You can do it the way you've currently got it, but then try casting every member of your list to Bird and catching a [ClassCastException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html) before trying to fly. If the cast succeeds, you've got a Bird and can fly.

Comment: All this said, for all the hemming and hawing I've seen about why `instanceof` is bad, I've ended up relying on it in production code more times than I care to count. it's Java's internal NPE-safe way of saying "this object is a member of that class."